# Javascript partly not working in html code

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Part of my javascript doesn't seem to be working as I want it to.

in my HTML I have

```
<div id="register" title="Register Here">
    <form action="Registers" id="registerForm" name="registerForm"
        method="post">
        Username:
        <br /> 
        Password:
        Confirm Password:
        <br /> Email:
        <br />
        <input type="submit" id="submit" value="Register" />
        <a href=#lognew> Log into your account </a>
    </form>
</div>

<div id="Login" title="Login Here">
    <form action="Login" class="input" method="post">
        User Name:
        <br /> 
        Password:
        <br /> 
       <input type="submit" value="Sign in" />
       <a href=#regnew> Create an account </a>
    </form>
</div>
```

And for my javascript I have

```
<script>    
    $("#regnew").click(function() {
        $("#Login").dialog("close");
        $("#register").dialog("open");
    });

    $("#lognew").click(function() {
        $("#Login").dialog("open");
        $("#register").dialog("close");
    });

    $("#register").dialog({
        autoOpen : false
    });

    $("#reg").click(function() {
        $("#register").dialog("open");
        $("#Login").dialog("close");
    });

    $("#Login").dialog({
        autoOpen : false
    });
    $("#log").click(function() {
        $("#Login").dialog("open");
        $("#register").dialog("close");
    });
</script>
```

The register, reg, login and log seem to work fine, however I can't get the regnew and lognew to work at all. It was working before but somehow broke.

Not sure what's wrong.

Thanks for your time.

Comment: `$("#regnew")` selects the element with the ID of `regnew` which you don't have. Same for lognew

Comment: aaaah! I put them between a div with the id and worked. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 2):

In your html replace:

```
<a href='#lognew'> Log into your account </a>
<a href='#regnew'> Create an account </a>
```

with

```
<a id='lognew' href='#'> Log into your account </a>
<a id='regnew' href='#'> Create an account </a>
```

`$('#lognew')` and `$('#regnew')` target `id`'s not `href` properties.